# -bash: mysql: command not found on wamp 2.5

Tags: wamp

i am trying to log into mysql from my command line.

i first went to this directory:

```
cd c/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin
```

i then did this:

> mysql -u root -p

but i got this error message:

> -bash: mysql: command not found

i should be able to connect automtically to mysql from my command line. i mean that mysql should be available.

this is what is in the mysql directory from my command line:

```
echo.exe                        mysqladmin.exe
innochecksum.exe                mysqlbinlog.exe
my_print_defaults.exe           mysqlcheck.exe
myisam_ftdump.exe               mysqld.exe
myisamchk.exe                   mysqld_multi.pl
myisamlog.exe                   mysqld-debug.exe
myisampack.exe                  mysqldump.exe
mysql.exe                       mysqldumpslow.pl
mysql_client_test.exe           mysqlhotcopy.pl
mysql_client_test_embedded.exe  mysqlimport.exe
mysql_config.pl                 mysqlshow.exe
mysql_config_editor.exe         mysqlslap.exe
mysql_convert_table_format.pl   mysqltest.exe
mysql_embedded.exe              mysqltest_embedded.exe
mysql_plugin.exe                perror.exe
mysql_secure_installation.pl    replace.exe
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql.exe         resolveip.exe
mysql_upgrade.exe
```

i would appreciate any advice

Comment: This looks a bit confusing: you have a bunch of `*.exe`'s on the other hand you're using Bash and forward slashes … Are you on a Windows or on a Linux machine?

Comment: hi Ixg. i am on windows.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a GIT Bash (or something similiar) window instead of a standard Windows Command window???

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this???